# Need help translating a few words

Tags: translation, word-choice, word-requests

So far I have deciphered them, but it makes no sense.

[image]

Comment: Also, all i could translate was 5 sheep, as the first 2 characters, but it doesn't make sense. any help appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

五羊牌
牌: brand.
五羊(five sheeps) is the brand name.

广州市
Guangzhou City

广州制帽厂
Guangzhou hat factory

出品
produced, product

规格
specification

Reasonably, the whole thing in English might become something like (stuff that you can leave out for a nicer translation is between square brackets):
Wuyang [Hats]
A product of Guangzhou Hat Factory [in Guangzhou]

specifications

Comment: 五羊as a brand in China is Five Rams in English, and the picture shows they are not sheep, but just goats.